# Is "stood time" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know there is an idiomatic expression in English for something to "stand the test of time" (by the way, would it be possible for something to "stand to the test" or stand *other* types of test?). But I'm pretty sure I've heard many times people saying that a certain something (e.g., a book) "stood time" (= "stood the test of time").

Is the phrase "this movie stood time" correct in this sense? Or is it bad English?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are asking if "stood time" can replace "stood the test of time", then I 'd have to say no.

Comment: @BillyKerr This is exatcly my question:) But is this phrase acceptable in any other context? That is, can it ever be correctly used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To stand the test of time* is an idiom, which means that the group of words have a meaning. If you remove words or take the words apart, they stop having the idiomatic meaning.

So you can never say '*This movie stood time*' if you want to say that a movie aged well.

The correct expression should always be '*This movie stood the test of time*'.

Comment: Likewise, you can't "stand the test" of things other than time.  "The movie stood the test of the audience," (to try to say that it was popular) would **not** work, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! As a matter of fact, using google I could only find "stood time *'s test* "; the few occurences of "stood time" only indeed seem wrong